# Onsen UIを使った背景の画像

Tags: monaca, html, onsen-ui

Onsen UIを使用して背景に画像を張りたいのですが

HTMLのCSSを使用して

```
body { background-image : url("画像");
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

としてるのですが変わりません

Onsen UIのスタイルシートを使用し変更した方が良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

そうですね、OnsenUIのCSSを編集した方がいいかと思います。
IDEでweinreのコンソールって触っておりますか？
デバッグアプリを起動中にElementにマウスカーソルを当てると
対象にしているDOMが見えるのでどのクラスに当てればいいか分かるかと思います。

また、OnsenUIで表示されるページはBODYの上に乗っかっているDOMです。
ですのでBODYに何かを設定しても、実際に上に乗っているものが見えるので見えません

暫くOnsenUI触って無いので対象に自信がないですが、
`.page`とか`.page__content`とかのクラスにくっついていたかと思います。

---

**コメントより追記**

> Onsen UIのV1およびV2で確認したところ、style.cssなどでpage__backgroundクラスを書き換えれば、背景‌​の画像を表示することができるようです。

Comment: `Onsen UI`の`V1`および`V2`で確認したところ、`style.css`などで`page__background`クラスを書き換えれば、背景の画像を表示することができるようです。